# how to get next object from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying the list of items, and when I delete the current item, how should I get the next item? Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList = (itemsList() |filter:{status: code}|orderBy: 'Time'| orderBy:'sortingOrder')" ng-init="initCurrentItem(item,$index)">    
<div id="itemRow" ng-click="selectedItem(item,$index)" 
                  ng-class="{'active':getCurrentItem().index === $index}">
     <div id="listRowContent">                       
     <div>{{item.name}}</div>
     <div>{{item.type}}/div>
     <div> {{item.Time}}</div>
```

It is displaying the list of items and I am displaying detailed items in other section. Here is my controller:

```
$scope.itemsList = function () {
        return ListService.getItemsList();
    };

    $scope.initCurrentItem = function(item,index){

      if(index === 0){          
        $scope.selectedList(item,index);
      }  
    };

    $scope.selectedList= function(currentList,index){    
        currentList.index = index;
       $scope.currentListDetails = currentList;
        }
    };
$scope.getCurrentMail = function(){
return $scope.currentListDetails;
}
```

In my controller, I am getting `itemslist` from a service and displaying the list in one section and highlighting the first element using `getCurrentItem()`. I am displaying a detailed list in another section. Now, when I select an item and delete it, it is highlighting the next one, but still showing the deleted list item details in detailed section. How do I get next element so that I can assign that object in to my `currentListDetails`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your list is not updated after you delete the selected item. You can either 'reload', and get all the list by reassigning the list i.e   `$scope.currentList = whateverservice.getList()`; 
or when you delete your element you can search also in your currentList `$scope.currentList.indexOf(deletedElement)`, 
then delete that element using splice(int,int) method. I prefer to you the second method, only one request whereas the first costs 2 requests.